# pyinstaller python

Tags: python, python-3.x

я новичок в разработке Python, захотел сделать мою программу саморазархивирующийся(exe). Сам pyinstaller вроде скачался нормально, однако при создании exe создается лишь одна папка "**pycache**"[image: Вот само создание exe файла]  [image: Вот так выглядит место куда должен был сохраниться exe файл] Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен если вы мне поможете!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае Вы находитесь в директории [image: C:\Users\yarik], следовательно используя pyinstaller, Вы создаете папку **bulid с exe** файлом по выше указаной директории, то бишь системной папке**C:\Users\yarik**
Надеюсь смог ответить на Ваш вопрос.